# How get all historical record in KSQL kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I have created a stream and i am writing KSQL on that stream .
But when i run this query and data arrive i can see records but when i data is not arriving and i run that query i do not see any older records .

So this is my KSQL

```
LOG_DIR=./ksql_logs /usr/local/confluent/bin/ksql http://localhost:8088


CREATE STREAM AUDIT_EVENT ( ID VARCHAR , VERSION VARCHAR , ACTION_TYPE VARCHAR , EVENT_TYPE VARCHAR , CLIENT_ID VARCHAR , DETAILS VARCHAR , OBJECT_TYPE VARCHAR , UTC_DATE_TIME VARCHAR , POINT_IN_TIME_PRECISION VARCHAR , TIME_ZONE VARCHAR , TIMELINE_PRECISION VARCHAR , GROUP_ID VARCHAR , OBJECT_DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR , OBJECT_ID VARCHAR , USER_DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR , USER_ID VARCHAR , PARENT_EVENT_ID VARCHAR , NOTES VARCHAR , SUMMARY VARCHAR , AUDIT_EVENT_TO_UTC_DT VARCHAR , AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_PITP VARCHAR , AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_TZ VARCHAR , AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_TP VARCHAR ) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='AVRO-AUDIT_EVENT', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');


SELECT * FROM "AUDIT_EVENT" WHERE CLIENT_ID='fgh-5d1e-17a2-9749-0e4d00';
```

I have created table and tried but i table also i can not see my older records .

Is there any way i can records when ever i run this query ?

Answer (score 1):

`SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest'` before your SELECT query statement.

Comment: See also [Troubleshooting KSQL – Part 1: Why Isn’t My KSQL Query Returning Data?](https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1/)